# Byte with Integer comparsion not working

Tags: android, ternary-operator

I have simple code fragment

```
getMarkerCode() == -1 ? null : getMarker(getMarkerCode());
```

where `getMarkerCode()` always return -1 (byte type). But every time runs `getMarker(getMarkerCode())` method.

Even if modify condition to:

```
if(getMarkerCode() == (byte)-1)
    return null;
else
    return getMarker(getMarkerCode());
```

result not changed. What's wrong?

It's posible without wrapping to `Byte` class?

Byte.compare(byte, byte) require SDK >= 19, but application supports API level 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected, the problem is **Instant Run** option in Android studio. I disable it and problem is gone.

Be careful with Instant run

Answer (score 0):

[Referring to this post](http://www.java2s.com/Book/Java/0060__Development/Compare_two_byte_values.htm) You should use `compareTo` using Byte instead of byte as `@Sergey` pointed in the comment. You can easily do it since you are istantiating "by hand" you will have no problems changing the type.

Than the Byte should probably be istantiated like `new Byte("-1")`

```
new Byte("-1").compareTo(getMarkerCode()) == 0 ? null : getMarker(getMarkerCode());
```

Results are:

```
Returns           | Meaning
--------------------------------------------------------------------
0                 |   if this Byte is equal to the argument Byte;
less than 0       |   if this Byte is numerically less than the argument Byte;
greater than 0    |   if this Byte is numerically greater than the argument Byte (signed comparison).
```

## Note

from byte to Byte you can simply cast

```
byte b; 
//plus instantiating
//...
Byte bObj = b;
```

Comment: `compareTo` method member of `Byte` class. Primitive type `byte` is not contain this

Comment: @Sergey thanks! I didn't think about it, I edited the answer

Comment: Thanks, Pier! But I wish compare values without wrapping to Byte class. It's posible? Your solution is not a secret :)

Comment: @Sergey true, But you know, here people asks for how to do 1+1 so I tried:P  Aaaaanyway. did you try `((int)getMarkerCode()) == -1`?

Comment: Thanks for work, Pier. I'm [solved](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41449405/3926506) the problem